# Personal Loan without CIBIL check?

Tags: india, credit-score, credit, credit-history, personal-loan

I have Low CIBIL score. Its take another 1 year for me to improve CIBIL score. But now I have to apply for a loan Rs.100000. I am salaried employee in private sector. And my CIBIL score is 628. Is there any bank that provides personal loan without check CIBIL core?

Answer (score 1):

First Low CIBIL score does not mean no loan.

Most banks [if not all] do check CIBIL score. If the score is low, they may not give you loan or ask to you get a guarantor or provide some collateral. Further if the score is low, the rate of interest could also be high.

Shop around for small co-operative banks that may grant loan with low CIBIL score. Please disclose your CIBIL score upfront, you do not want to many enquiries on your score. To many enquiries on score will also reduce the score.

Comment: thanks for your continues answer. Can u provide some banks that provide personal loan for low cibil score?. I asked co-operative bank nearby, but they not giving personal loan for salaried employee.

Comment: I applied Personal loan in AXIS Bank Salary Account. But they also rejected because of low cibil. But i need urgent money . Dont know which bank to give loan for low cibil.